# Fibonacci Iterative Move In Array[]

Tags: java, arrays, do-while, fibonacci

My goal is to write a method showing how the fibonacci sequence moves. I have to use an array and equation to show how the numbers move on the array (thus iterating the value using fibonacci method: previous number + current number = next number).

This is the logic that I want to use with array[] as representation:

```
    n = fibonacci number
    i = 1;
    previousNumber = 0 
    nextNumber = 1 
    sum = previousNumber + nextNumber;
    while (i <= n) {
    sum = previousNumber + nextNumber;
    previousNumber = nextNumber;
    nextNumber = sum;

return nextNumber;
```

I went this far and I am stuck:

```
long fibonacci(int fibonacci) {
    int[] fib = new int[20];
    if (fibonacci < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n value cannot be negative number");
    }
    if (fibonacci == 0 || fibonacci == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    int i ;
    for (i = 2; i < fibonacci; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[0] + fib[1];
        fib[0] = fib[1];
        fib[1] = fib[i]; 
    }
    return fib[i];
}
```

The returned value seems ok. In the fibonacci test, fib from 5 is  5 and 4 is 3. What worries me is how this string looks on the debugger. The way I move them makes them look like this : {3,5,2,3,5} and it should be {1,1,2,3,5}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an array.

```
long fibonacci(int fibonacci) {
    if (fibonacci < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n value cannot be negative number");
    }
    if (fibonacci == 0 || fibonacci == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    first = 1;
    second = 1;
    sum i;
    for (i = 2; i <= fibonacci; i++) {
        sum = first + second;
        first  = second;
        second = sum; 
    }
   return sum;
}
```

This implementation is simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong. It should be:

```
for (i = 2; i <= fibonacci; i++) {
    fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
}
return fib[i-1];
```

You should never change `fib[0]` and `fib[1]`, and `fib[i]` should be the sum of the previous two elements.

If the goal was to calculate `fib(i)` without an array, you would need two variables to keep track of the last two values:

```
long fibonacci(int fibonacci) {
    if (fibonacci < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n value cannot be negative number");
    }
    if (fibonacci == 0 || fibonacci == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int beforeLast = 1;
    int last = 1;
    int i;
    int fib = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= fibonacci; i++) {
        fib = last + beforeLast;
        beforeLast = last;
        last = fib;
    }
    return fib;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your method should look like:

```
static long fibonacci(int fibonacci) {
        int[] fib = new int[20];
        if (fibonacci < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n value cannot be negative number");
        }
        if (fibonacci == 0 || fibonacci == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        fib[0] = 1;
        fib[1] = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i < fibonacci; i++) {
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]; // change here
        }
        return fib[i-1]; // change here
    }
```

Comment: Hi Piotr, I forgot to mention but I can't use recursion for this one.

Comment: Hi Jakub, it is not a recurrsion - it's just returning last computed element of an array - exactly like you did :)